# Remove Facebook Like which was not posted

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I clicked facebook "like" on the web-page I was testing. In the dialog which appeared I clicked "Close" rather than "Post". Now here is 1 like (from this user), and no entry in users "like" pages in facebook account.

So user (seemingly) could not remove this like.

Whether this is a bug of FaceBook, or there is some special way to remove such likes?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way at last. Though really, in some cases "like" is not posted to wall/news of user's page, it could be still deleted from "activity log".

One should go to profile page (link with one's name at the top bar, to the right of "home" link) - some with url like

https://www.facebook.com/firstname.lastname

Here the button "Activity Log" could be seen which leads to url like

https://www.facebook.com/firstname.lastname/allactivity

and here all "likes" are anyway mentioned, even if they were not posted to wall. Deleting them from here brings up "Unlike" dialog which completes the process.